# How to make Gini coefficient in Lorenz curve in livelihood income

Tags: r

I want to create a Gini coefficient-Lorenz curve on an R graph to investigate income inequality. Specifically, I want to examine how forest livelihood sources can minimize income inequalities and how income inequalities increase in the absence of forest-related income sources.